# Set GridLayout row height in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

Very straight forward question, if you have a GridLayout defined in Vaadin, how can you set the height of all / individual rows? E.g:

```
mainLayout = new GridLayout(2, 7);
mainLayout.setMargin(true);
mainLayout.setWidth("100%");
mainLayout.setHeight("100%");
// Set row[s] height?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rekommend you to read the [following chapter in the book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.gridlayout.html).

It will explain how you set fullsize on grids and individual rows and how individual rows and columns can have different spacings.

Example from the book:

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,2);

// Layout containing relatively sized components must have
// a defined size, here is fixed size.
grid.setWidth("600px");
grid.setHeight("200px");

// Add some content
String labels [] = {
        "Shrinking column<br/>Shrinking row",
        "Expanding column (1:)<br/>Shrinking row",
        "Expanding column (5:)<br/>Shrinking row",
        "Shrinking column<br/>Expanding row",
        "Expanding column (1:)<br/>Expanding row",
        "Expanding column (5:)<br/>Expanding row"
};
for (int i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
    Label label = new Label(labels[i], Label.CONTENT_XHTML);
    label.setWidth(null); // Set width as undefined
    grid.addComponent(label);
}

// Set different expansion ratios for the two columns
grid.setColumnExpandRatio(1, 1);
grid.setColumnExpandRatio(2, 5);

// Set the bottom row to expand
grid.setRowExpandRatio(1, 1);

// Align and size the labels.
for (int col=0; col<grid.getColumns(); col++) {
    for (int row=0; row<grid.getRows(); row++) {
        Component c = grid.getComponent(col, row);
        grid.setComponentAlignment(c, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);

        // Make the labels high to illustrate the empty
        // horizontal space.
        if (col != 0 || row != 0)
            c.setHeight("100%");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marthin, so basically check out the .setRowExpandRatio() method

Comment: Yes I guess it depends on the exact result you are looking for but probably that will do it!