# How to adjust GridLayout row height dynamically?

Tags: java, vaadin, grid-layout

I am using Vaadin, and I have set of data in given `GridLayout`.

Inside Grid I have Labels as Key and Value:

[image]

Requirement is:

[image]

Situation is, now Value i.e. Label could have longer text which I can wrap text but I also want to dynamically increase that particular row height accordingly. How it can be done using `GridLayout`? I have tried `setRowExpandRatio()` but didn't helped.

Comment: some helpful information is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350978/set-gridlayout-row-height-in-vaadin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this situation, I chose `CustomLayout` with html template. through this way I got very easy control over my grid or in other word Table.
**mylayout.html** (VAADIN/themes/mythemes/layouts)

```
<table class="tg">
   <tr>
     <td class="tg-031e tg-0ord">Key1</td>
     <td class="tg-031e" location="Key1_value"></td>
     <td class="tg-031e tg-0ord">Key2</td>
     <td class="tg-031e" location="Key2_value"></td>
     <td class="tg-031e" colspan="2" rowspan="9" location="image_value" style="width: 245px;">  
       <img src="" />  
     </td>
   </tr>  
   <tr> ... </tr>  
</table>
```

Then inside my code, I used it in following way:

```
CustomLayout customLayout = new CustomLayout("mylayout");  
customLayout.addComponent(new Label("Key1_value"), "Key1_value");
```

and so on..
I found this solution comparatively more elegant and clean. if it could be acheived with other way please let us all know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` has an `addComponent` method to create "cells" that span more than one column/row.

> ```
>    public void addComponent(Component component,
>                          int column1,
>                          int row1,
>                          int column2,
>                          int row2)
>                   throws GridLayout.OverlapsException,
>                          GridLayout.OutOfBoundsException
> ```
>
> Adds a component to the grid in the specified area.
>   The area is defined by specifying the upper left corner (column1, row1)
>   and the lower right corner (column2, row2) of the area.
>   The coordinates are zero-based.
>
> If the area overlaps with any of the existing components already 
>   present in the grid, the operation will fail and an
>   GridLayout.OverlapsException is thrown.

Comment: your suggestion will work for spanning row and column, i.e. predetermined process. issue is to auto resize that particular row on runtime depending upon cell content.

Comment: `GridLayout` calculates "absolute" positions as soon as items are added to it, so even though it's possible to change contents of individual cells afterwards, the "layout" as such cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks @geert3. this added some contrasting feature about GridLayout to my knowledge. So I think CustomLayout is the only way to go ?

Comment: @agpt Actually I was wrong. By invoking `removeComponent(int, int)` followed by other `addComponent`s Vaadin *WILL* rearrange the layout. Key is to remove the old slot first. So I guess we're both adding to our knowledge ;-)